# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes)

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I was trying to move my Magento 2 website from local to the server! I was trying to upgrade and clear the cache but I am getting the error message '**Fatal error: The allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted**'

using :Php 7.1 and Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1

[image: error]

of course, this problem is self-explained, But the real problem is I am unable to increase the memory size

1. MultiPHP INI Editor
   updated -756M

2.[Magento2-root-folder]/index.php
ini_set('memory_limit',256);

3.[Magento2-root-folder]/.user.ini
memory_limit = 768M

4.[Magento2-root-folder]/.htaccess (2 places)
php_value memory_limit 768M

5.[Magento2-root-folder]/pub/.user.ini
memory_limit = 768M

6.[Magento2-root-folder]/pub/.htaccess (2 places)
php_value memory_limit 768M

I have tried all these places, please let me know where I am wrong ! Where else I can try to increase

Answer (score 2):

You need to just run the comand line with memory_limit

```
      php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento c:c
      
      php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento s:u

      php -dmemory_limit=2G bin/magento s:s:d -f
```

**I hope this is helpful to you!!**